# The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes

The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

getting this error message..
since 2 dayz..
tried all googling..
its still there

Comment: One suggestion - perhaps try checking the 'Upload Later' checkbox and using Apple's separate Cocoa uploader. Sometimes that works better. Also, it can sometimes leave information in the OS X Console.app if it fails.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After two days of fighting this problem, the solution for me was to make sure there are no two files that differ only in capitalization. So Foo.png and foo.png in the same directory within your app will cause this error.

Here are things to check that I have collected from different websites during these two days:

- check the finals steps in the build log "ProcessingProductPackaging" and "CodeSign"
- make sure you aren't accidentally including any .svn directories or similar
- make sure you have the correct distribution profile in projects settings for the release mode and it is not overriden by target settings
- in your pbxproj file, check PROVISIONING_PROFILE and CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY lines for Release mode or delete them and set the right profile again in project settings
- use Finder's compress instead of the terminal's zip command
- check the output of codesign -vvvv MyApp.app
- check the output of codesign -dvvvv MyApp.app
- check the output of codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists' MyApp.app
- if uploading with Safari doesn't work, try Firefox
- icon must be 57x57
- use application uploader to get a more informative error message
- there must not be spaces or special characters anywhere in the path of the zip you upload
- check your keychain: do you have a distribution certificate that is associated with a private key?
- make sure you set the Active SDK to device and not simulator when building
- open the .app file with Show Contents and check whether it contains a file embedded.mobileprovision with the UUID of you distribution profile, and a folder _CodeSignature with CodeResources inside
- make sure you bundle identifer matches the AppID. For an AppID XYZ.com.mycompany.* a valid bundle identifier is com.mycompany.myappname
- build on Mac Extended filesystem, not fat32
- try removing provisioning profiles from XCode, empty caches (XCode menu -> Empty Caches), restarting XCode, adding the profile again

Answer (score 5):

If you have followed the instructions in http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action, then I can come up with the following things that could cause this error:

- The certificate/keys/provisioning profile used for signing were incorrect
- The certificate has expired
- The zip is broken (it contains a couple of symbolic links that will get broken if you don't make the zip as is told in the instructions)
- There is entitlements.plist file in your app bundle

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Xcode 4, my Distribution build got confused with my Release build within the "Scheme" configuration.  I was able to fix by doing the following:

1. In Xcode 4, go to Product > Manage Schemes...
2. Select target/scheme, press Edit button
3. Select Archive action
4. Change Build Configuration from Release to Distribution

I was getting the "Invalid Binary" and "Invalid Signature" message from Apple after uploading to iTunes Connect.  Checked and double-check my provisioning, certificates and other build settings and COULD NOT find the problem.  Guess my Archive scheme was set up to build Release rather than Distribution.  Very lame and very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding two new keys to my entitlements plist - application-identifier and keychain-access-groups:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>T9YRD11G97.com.duncancampbell.fontagious</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>T9YRD11G97.com.duncancampbell.fontagious</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I got the "T9YRD11G97" from AppID in the provisioning profile, and the "com.duncancampbell.fontagious" from the BundleID in iTunesConnect.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the process can be very frustrating.  I'm sorry you've already spent two days on this but it sounds like you are close.

To follow on from Lauri's response did you verify the information in the "Verifying a Successful Distribution Build" section of the instructions for building the application for distribution?

Specifically checking that you have included the correct "embedded.mobileprovision” file in the build as well as verifying that the app was signed with the correct certificate?

Comment: i tries all these u suggested..but still not working

Comment: Please include the build transcript output for "codeSign" and "embedded.mobileprovision".  This will allow us to help you more specifically.  Without that we are just making general suggestions.  

Also, did you try Hunter's suggestion above to try using the Application Uploader?

Comment: solved..
gone through almost all the forums finally solved..

Comment: problem was developer provisining profile was configured..

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a space in my project name that was causing the invalid signature error.  When I checked the build log, I looked at the lines referring to the distribution certificate and I saw there was a space in the file path.  Removing the space in my project name fixed it, hopefully this saves someone a lot of trouble.